# Datetime does not contain definition for "ToTimeStamp"

Tags: c#

This line:

```
var time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimestamp();
```

gives me an error:

```
Datetime does not contain definition for "ToTimeStamp"
```

Context:

```java
public static string GenerateEncPassword(string password, string publicKey, string keyId, string version) {
    var time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimestamp(); // Unix timestamp
    ...
}
    
private static readonly DateTime _jan1St1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static long ToTimestamp(this DateTime d) {
    return (long)(d.ToUniversalTime() - _jan1St1970).TotalSeconds;
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Please can you explain why you expect it to contain `.ToTimestamp()` and what you expect this method to do?

Comment: I'm trying to implement this code I found on GitHub to generate an encrypted password 
https://gist.github.com/huoshan12345/44b1b4927b21d4ec21d1cbd61ea659da

Comment: @MiguelDey - The `ToTimestamp` method is defined right in the github code you posted.

Comment: Okay I see that, but why is it giving that error?

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs [state here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#orderby-example) (see also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method#to-define-and-call-the-extension-method)) that extension methods

> [need to be] defined inside a non-nested, non-generic static class

so in order to make the code example work, we need to put the `ToTimestamp` method inside a `static` class.

```cs
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    private static readonly DateTime _jan1St1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public static long ToTimestamp(this DateTime d) 
    {
        return (long)(d.ToUniversalTime() - _jan1St1970).TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that the class can be named however you want to.</sub>

---

Then, the `ToTimeStamp` method can be used like this:

```cs
public class PasswordHelper
{
    public static string GenerateEncPassword(string password, string publicKey, string keyId, string version) 
    {
        var time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToTimestamp(); // Unix timestamp
        ...
    }
}
```